# Spring TypeFilter for method annotations to be used in ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#findCandidateComponents

Tags: spring

Is there an existing Spring `org.springframework.core.type.filter.TypeFilter` implementation for Method annotations?

I am looking to call `ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider#findCandidateComponents` in order got get all of the components that have an annotation or inherited annotations so I can validate the state of the configuration supports the annotation attribute values.

There is an `org.springframework.core.type.filter.AnnotationTypeFilter`, is there a similar implementation but getting classes that have methods that are annotated with the annotation?

If not is there a mechanism to search for components with methods with a specified annotation?

Comment: What is it you want to achieve? Component scanning is used to detect classes for which instances need to be created, looks like you want to do something else.

Comment: There is text configuration added to the annotation `@Foo(value="label")` ...the matchup for that text is in an @Configuration, @Bean structure, `@Bean Map<String, Configvalues> fooConfig() {...}`.  The methods are surrounded by an aspect triggered by the annotation @Foo.  We want to look at the annotation, validate the label specified is present in the configuration, functionally `(Assert.notNull(fooConifg.containsKey(annotation.label)); }`. This is so that the developer doesn't think just adding the annotation is enough.

Comment: Sorry, my previous  response didn't save (my fault)

We are trying to look for classes that have methods with an annotation to put a proxy around that method so that we can handle it dynamically.  Originally we were using an ImportBeanRegistryPostProcessor, but resolved this through the use of the BeanFactoryPostProcessor.  So It's resolved because we don't need to use a scanner to find candidates, we've got the implemented beans.